# Android socket connection takes too long

Tags: android, sockets

In my application, I make a TCP/IP Socket Connection. I run this Application on a HTC incredible S. But it needs very long and after a little while a dialog shows up, which says that my application doesn't react. The Dialog offers me the options to "force a closing" or to "wait". Then I choose "wait" and everything works fine and my HTC is connected.

The dialog doesn't appear when I test the application on a Motorola Zoom, because it is much faster.

My question is, if there is a way to force my phone to wait longer so that no dialog appears?

Thanks

Comment: it´s very hard to figure out your problem without and source examples how you implemented the socket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform long operations on a background thread, and not on the UI (main) thread. Android provides some great solutions for it, where I think the most popular is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Great articles to read about it are [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html), and [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html), which might also help.